# Why is there no build API of the Telegram iOS app?

Tags: python, swift, xcode, telegram

Good afternoon, I'm trying to build a Telegram project.
When I try to build the project I get the following error.

MacOS 12.1
Xcode 13.3 (13E113)
Bazel 5.0.0
m1

For assembly I use the official readme [Git](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS.git) with this script:

```
python3 build-system/Make/Make.py \
--cacheDir="$HOME/telegram-bazel-cache" \
build \
--configurationPath="$HOME/telegram-configuration" \
--buildNumber=100001 \
--configuration=release_universal
```

I understand that the error starts with this line, the necessary files are not created, but why?

```
Warning: /Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-input/bazel-5.0.0-x86_64: No such
```

It can't install the right version of Bazel according to the line in Make.py?
Full text of the error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-input/bazel-5.0.0-x86_64: No such 
Warning: file or directory
100     9  100     9    0     0     33      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    34
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-system/Make/Make.py", line 638, in <module>
    bazel_path = locate_bazel(base_path=os.getcwd())
  File "/Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-system/Make/BazelLocation.py", line 17, in locate_bazel
    call_executable([
  File "/Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-system/Make/BuildEnvironment.py", line 60, in call_executable
    subprocess.check_call(resolved_arguments, env=resolved_env)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/curl', '-L', 'https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/5.0.0/bazel-5.0.0-x86_64', '--output', '/Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-input/bazel-5.0.0-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 23.
```

Answer (score 1):

As of late March, 2022, there are several bugs in the latest commit (`702f254`) of Telegram iOS:

1. `build-input` is not automatically created: `mkdir build-input`
2. Downloading script of Bazel has bugs sometimes:

   ```sh
   # In Telegram-iOS
   curl -L https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/5.0.0/bazel-5.0.0-darwin-x86_64 --output build-input/bazel-5.0.0-x86_64
   # For Apple Silicon Macs:
   curl -L https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/5.0.0/bazel-5.0.0-darwin-arm64 --output build-input/bazel-5.0.0-darwin-arm64
   ```
3. The latest push has a dependency bug. Please `git checkout 2a32c8718`

About one week ago, I wrote a blog post about it: https://blog.wildcat.io/2022/03/build-and-debug-telegram-ios/

Answer (score 0):

create build-input and try again

The first time you install and download, there will be a security prompt. I tried to download manually, and after executing the command, in the system security settings, clicked to open

```
mkdir -p /Users/igrssv/Telegram-iOS/build-input

python3 build-system/Make/Make.py \
--cacheDir="$HOME/telegram-bazel-cache" \
build \
--configurationPath="$HOME/telegram-configuration" \
--buildNumber=100001 \
--configuration=release_universal
```